# What can cause scroll to not work on mobile

Tags: css, scroll, touch

I have a section of the site where scroll stops working (touch device). So when you scroll to that point and try to scroll down more, scroll not happening and you can't go no up no down.

My question is this, what can cause scroll to stop working generally on mobile device. I think that something to do with CSS, but I can't catch this problem still.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Code example please.

Comment: The code is too complicated and since I can't understand what causing the problem I can't simplify it for you. So my question is more general. What css properties can cause scroll to stop working.

Comment: Overflow property can, https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Comment: There is probably a `div` that has its own (hidden?) scrollbars. That way you reach a point where you are not scrolling the page but the inner `div`.

Comment: Can you like post a link of the real website so we can check it?

Comment: Link to site is: https://coolpickz.com/ The section of "Football League Winners!" when opened in Nexus 7 tablet real device in landscape mode, you can see all 5 colmns, but once you try to scroll inside this columns container, it doesn't work. I tried to remove overflows, but have no luck so far detecting which one is actually causing the problem.